# How to replace comma and point from a string

Tags: javascript, string, numbers

I get a number format string from an input box like: 1,033.00
How can I convert it to 1033 by jquery/javascript?
I have to use this converted number to add it with another number.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a string replace `numberString= numberString.replace ( /[^0-9]/g, '' );`

To add it to another number you can use `+` operator to convert the numberString to a number value.

`var numberString= numberString.replace ( /[^0-9]/g, '' );
var addition = +numberString + anotherNumber;`